# Streaming Video from RTMP to EMGUCV

Tags: c#, opencv, ffmpeg, emgucv

I'm trying to stream a webcam using RTMP to an EMGUCV project in order to process the video. I have set up a private RTMP server in a linux box using this tutorial, 
https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/

I'm testing the webcam stream using ffmpeg with the following commands,

- Write to the rtmp server using,

  ```
  ffmpeg -y -f vfwcap -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i 0 -an -f flv rtmp://rtmp-server:1935/live/stream
  ```
- Read from the rtmp server using,
      ffplay -fflags nobuffer rtmp://rtmp-server:1935/live/stream -loglevel verbose

I'm able to write a simple OpenCV C++ application to read the stream and display it. Code below,

```
    cv::VideoCapture vcap;
    cv::Mat image;
    const std::string videoStreamAddress = "rtmp://rtmp-server:1935/live/stream";
    if(!vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)) {
        printf("Error opening video stream or file");
        return -1;
    }

    cv::namedWindow("Output Window");
    cv::Mat edges;
    for(;;) {
        if(!vcap.read(image)) {
            printf("No frame");
            cv::waitKey();
        }
        cv::imshow("Output Window", image);
        if(cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
    }
return 0;
```

The above code works properly. However when I try it using EMGUCV C#, I get the error message
`unable to create to capture from rtmp://rtmp-server:1935/live/stream`

This is my C# Code,

```
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private static Capture _cameraCapture;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Run();
        }

        void Run()
        {
            try
            {
                _cameraCapture = new Capture("rtmp://192.168.56.101:1935/live/stream");                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                return;
            }            
        }
   }
```

Do I need a specific build of EMGUCV with FFMPEG or is RTMP capturing not available in EMGUCV?

Comment: Other protocols work properly?

Comment: If I try to initialize the Capture without any parameters, it opens up the default camera in the PC.